# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available

Tags: ejb, jndi

I created an EJB project and another project to test the first.
This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXgar.png) gives an overview about my two projects.
The class main on the test project is:

```html
public class TestEjb 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  GestionEmployeeRemote gestion = null;
  try {
   Properties jndiProperties = new Properties(); 
                        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming"); 
          Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
   Object o = context.lookup("ejb:/FirstEJBProject/GestionEmployee!services.GestionEmployeeRemote");
   gestion = (GestionEmployeeRemote) o;
  } catch (NamingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  createEmployee(gestion);
 }

 public static void createEmployee(GestionEmployeeRemote gestion)
 {
  Employee employee = new Employee("Foulen", "Ben Foulen", new Date(), "Directeur");
  gestion.createEmployee(employee);
 }
```

The file **jndi.properties** is:

```html
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT=false
```

The class **GestionEmployee.java** is:

```html
package services;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import persistance.Employee;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class GestionEmployee
 */
@Stateless
public class GestionEmployee implements GestionEmployeeRemote, GestionEmployeeLocal {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    public GestionEmployee() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 @Override
 public void createEmployee(Employee employee) {
  em.persist(employee);
  
 }

 @Override
 public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
  em.merge(employee);
  
 }

 @Override
 public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
  em.remove(employee);
  
 }

 @Override
 public Employee getEmployeeById(int idEmployee) {
  Employee elmployee = em.find(Employee.class, idEmployee);
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
  Query query = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e");
  return query.getResultList();
 }

}
```

The class **GestionEmployeeRemote.java** is:

```html
package services;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

import persistance.Employee;

@Remote
public interface GestionEmployeeRemote
{
 public void createEmployee (Employee employee);
 public void updateEmployee (Employee employee);
 public void deleteEmployee (Employee employee);
 public Employee getEmployeeById (int idEmployee);
 public List<Employee> getAllEmployee();
}
```

After running the class main, I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:FirstEJBProject, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@a47962
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:749)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:253)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:198)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.createEmployee(Unknown Source)
>       at test.TestEjb.createEmployee(TestEjb.java:37)
>       at test.TestEjb.main(TestEjb.java:31)

I'm looking for finding a solution for this issue, any help is appreciated.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please give your EJB version (3.0?3.1/3.2),GestionEmployee.java and  GestionEmployeeRemote.java.

Comment: Hello @Riadh, thanks a lot for your help.
The EJB version  is 3.1. I added the required classes to my question. Could you please take a look ?. Big thanks.

Comment: Try to add this line to your client: 
Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

Comment: Hi @Riadh, I appreciate your help, I made changes on TestEjb as you recommend (I modified the code above), but the same error persists. I got reference on this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84JTYAfk_jw which finished by success.However, for me I can't understand what I missed, I did as presented by this tutorial. Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: That's well! I'm using wildfly 10, and what I gave you, is what I have made for my apps. Good luck